# URL mod rewriting response 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my site URL, This gives me the error "500 Internal Server Error".
This is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?shopiId=5&shopName=$1 [L]
```

Please help.

Comment: does your server error log contain any information about the error?

Comment: Do you get the error with `RewriteEngine On` alone?

Comment: Maybe additionaly an `a2enmod rewrite` is required

Comment: @Spudley - How could I check the server error log brother?

Comment: @Michel - No errors on alone

Comment: I assume you use a shared hoster. There it could be realy difficould to check apache server log. Try to see webinterface of your hoster. Perhaps you will see there something. Have a look with ftp on the server. Do you see there a "logs" folder including a "error.log" file?  If you have an own rootserver try: "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?shopiId=5&shopName=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Dont start to section with a / because you dont like reffer to an absolute path.
This would realy mean /index.php
If you just write it without leading /, it would mean something like /var/www/index.php

You got a 500 error casued ba a infinity loop.

Additionaly you neet to add the QSA flag, otherwise you will get index.php as shopName

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Appreciate brother. Now Error is gone, but Urls are not working. When I click on any link, its just redirecting to the index page.

Comment: Are the .htaccess and the index.php file in the same directory? Can you please provide an exmaple url, that should be match?

Comment: yes, both are in the root folder
check this [link](http://noblenetwork.net/Eyepax)

Comment: Sorry i forget the QSA flag. I improved my answer.